# How to prevent a particular html page from getting default style?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am new to HTML and Ruby i have create one application , i put all my styles in application.HTML.ERB  file. It contains header footer styles which automatically applies to all HTML files in my project. Now i want to remove the default style for my show.HTML page. And also i don't need any header and footer for show.HTML page. How can i do this please any one help me.
 application.HTML.ERB

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Contact</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <header>
     <div class="al" >
  <div class = "logo">
     <img src="/data/contact.png" width="50px" height = "50px"/>
     </div>
     <div class="con">
     Contact Book
     </div>
        </div>
      </header>

   </head>
   <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
  <footer>
  <p align="center"> All text and design @2014 Report Bee Edusys Ltd.
  </p>
   </footer>
  </html>
```

Comment: add layout false in which controller u don't want that default style

Comment: Is your "show" template a complete html document, ie with a declaration, a `<head>`, and a `<body>`?  If so then `:layout => false` will work for you.  If not then you need to use a different layout instead of no layout.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use separate layout for one action in controller, Otherwise we can send layout while rendering a template

Try this

```
 layout nil  # no layout default is application
 layout 'application', :except => :show  # inheriting application except one action "show"
```

Comment: It would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add an explaination for your intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a different "layout" file, next to your `application.html.erb` file, then specify that layout in the action, like so:

```
render :action => "show", :layout => "my_new_layout"
```

If you have shared sections that you want in both layouts you can move them into partials then `render` the partial in each layout.

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html